# Is verse diagramming important to hermeneutics?

Tags: syntax

Just wondering if verse diagramming is vital to exegesis and hermeneutics.

Comment: Interesting question. Until you asked, I had no idea that there were programs to diagram the Hebrew/Greek scriptures. Are you asking about diagramming *English* translations of Scripture, or the original languages?  Diagramming Hebrew verses sounds intriguing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link to a discussion on the B-Greek forum called "Sentence Diagramming":

https://www.ibiblio.org/bgreek/forum/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=1877

Within the discussion, there are links to **phrasing** Greek text (not diagramming, per se):

http://www.ibiblio.org/koine/greek/phrasing/phrasing-greek-text.html

> 1. **What is Phrasing a Greek text?**
>
> A long Greek sentence with even moderately complex structure can be
> daunting. Lining out a Greek text is a way to break it down into
> manageable phrases, in the original order, using whitespace to show
> relationships among the phrases of the text. Phrasing a text not only
> makes it easier to see the relationships among the words, it also
> makes the sentences much easier to read out loud—most people who try
> it find that reading the text repeatedly out loud is a particularly
> good way to get a feel for a text. Many students approach complex
> Greek texts by hunting for subjects and verbs, then trying to fit the
> other phrases and subordinate clauses into the framework of these
> subjects and verbs, a process that is often unwieldy and
> self-defeating. Phrasing texts is an intuitive process that teaches
> how to recognize the natural underlying structure of a text.
>
> The goal of phrasing a text is to grasp the basic structure of the
> text, working in the original language, before turning to external
> aids such as lexicons or commentaries. You do not need to be an expert
> in the Greek language to phrase texts, but you do need to be able to
> read at least simple Greek texts with the help of a lexicon. In some
> ways, phrasing is like diagramming a sentence, but it is much simpler,
> can easily be done with any text editor that supports the Greek font
> in use, and preserves the original order of the words. If you know
> enough Greek to understand the relationship between independent and
> dependent verbs, and to identify the objects of a verb, you can phrase
> a Greek text....

Comment: thanks for your comments, I was asking about English texts, but I am now interested in trying to navigate original language texts.

Answer (score 1):

Diagramming is helpful to understand the meaning of a sentence. This is applicable to biblical texts. Since biblical hermeneutics considers the interpretation of biblical texts, finding the meaning of a given sentence is useful. Therefore, diagramming verses can contribute to biblical hermeneutics. This is especially useful for long, confusing sentences.

Comment: thank you for your response, I am searching for my first job as a pastor and am considering teaching others about text diagramming in the course of Bible study.